# Search for a file with part of the file name in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

There’s a folder with a file named “Physio_Invoice_June21_img001.jpg” and typing "Physio" into the search bar at the top turns up nothing. Why is this? I tried using regular expressions (including *) but it didn't help. How do I search when I only know part of the file name, and want to search all of my Google Drive?

Comment: If you change `_` to `-` in the actual filename do you get the same result?

Comment: That's a pretty lousy search if you already need to know the file name

Comment: If your file was Physio-Invoice-June21-img001.jpg it might turn up if you search for "invoice" or "physio" since the underscore joins the words together differently than a hyphen

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I have a work-around.  If you sync with the file system on your computer, you could use File Locator Lite, a lovely little program: https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite

Comment: @Celeritas: Add more details to your question like how do you uploaded the jpg file to Google Drive an screenshot showing the jpg file inside the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Something weird is happening.

## Explanation

AFAIK, Google Drive search work fine for partial file name searching, so I tried to reproduce the problem, but I can't.

What I did was:

1. I googled [jpg], selected an image,
2. saved it with the name given in the question<sup>1</sup>,
3. uploaded to Google Drive<sup>2</sup>.
4. Then I searched `Physio`.

The result was

[image: Drive Search results]

As you can see, the Google Drive search returned the file, as was expected, without using search operators or wildcards.

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup>: Physio_Invoice_June21_img001.jpg
<sup>2</sup>: Used drag from the desktop and drop to http://drive.google.com opened in Chrome.

Comment: How do you get it to search inside folders for files of that name?

Comment: @Celeritas I already told step by step what I did. I applied numbered list format to make it clear. By the other hand by default, Google Drive search search inside folders.

Comment: @Celeritas there is a box you can type in just to the right of the Google logo.  It has "Search Drive" written in it in light gray letters.